# Formula Field with Custom Metadata Type that is created in test method

Tags: apex, formula-field, metadata-api, test-setup

I have a test method that needs to assert the creation of a document, the creation of such document is blocked by the evaluation of a (Boolean) Formula Field that depends on a Custom Metadata Type with a list of values.

Can I create the CMDT with mock values within the test Method for the Formula field to evaluate with those values?

I don't want to evaluate anything around the CMDT nor the Formula Field in the test method. I just want to run the test and be able to get a TRUE in that formula field without having the CMDT values in the org, only within the test method.

Can that be possible? I can't find any documentation on this particular scenario, thanks!

Comment: If it weren't for the formula reference constraint, you can certainly mock CMDT Sobjects in memory for use in Unit tests if accessed by Apex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMDT isn't regular data. It's metadata. And like most metadata, it's actually available directly to the unit test, even without `SeeAllData=true`. Apex doesn't have a way to create actual CMDT records in a unit test, and since this is a formula, the data must be present. However, if you're making a managed package, you can supply CMDT and other metadata through [unpackaged metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm). You'll need to find another way to work around this limitation.

Comment: Nice, I see. Thanks for the answer @sfdcfox. Seems tricky in my scenario (with my current approach) as the CMDT contains Ids that I'm creating dynamically over the test method.